# Map string with json to map of maps in Spring Configuration

Tags: java, json, spring

I try to use String with json like this

```json
{ 
  "group1": { 
    "group11": { 
      "name": "element1", 
      "link": "<LINK>" 
    }, 
    "group12": {
      "name": "element2", 
      "link": "<LINK>"
    }
  },
  "group2": {
    "group21": {
      "name": "element3",
      "link": "<LINK>"
    }
  }
}
```

as configuration in my Spring application.

I added configuration like this in my application.yaml file:

```
my-config:
  string-with-json: ${STRING_JSON}
  other-option: string
```

and wrote property class:

```
@Data
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("my-config")
public class BaseImagesProperties {

    public Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>> stringWithJson;
    public String otherOption;

    public String getLink(String group, String element) {
        return stringWithJson.get(group).get(element).get("link");   
    }
}
```

When I started my app, it swears that he can't convert a string to Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>>

How can I properly convert it to this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best way is to rewrite this JSON to YML format and inject your configuration as Map with `@ConfigurationProperties`.

Here you can find some examples of how to use properties with Map:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-yaml-inject-map

The other way is to store it as a String and Inject it as a String with @Value annotation. After that, you will be able to use Jackson to convert your String to Map:

https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-map